# Using the OR in XPATH

Tags: html, xpath

I want to use a xpath to locate an html element which can be neither an input or neither a textarea. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div>
<label>Login</label>
<div>
<div>
<input/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<div>
<label>Full name</label>
<div>
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

To locate the input or the textarea I've made this xpath which is working:

```
//div[contains(label,'Login')]//input
```

or this one :

```
//div[contains(label,'Full name')]//textarea
```

The thing what text there is in the label I can have a textarea or an input element, so to locate the input or the teaxtarea I want to do something like this:

```
//div[contains(label,'Login')]//input|//div[contains(label,'Login')]//textarea
```

Where the | represent the OR, but it's not working. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` operator is the *union* operator, not OR, but it *should* work for what you're trying to do.

The following should also work, so please try this:

```
//div[contains(label,'Login')]//*[self::input or self::textarea]
```